# Amazon Prime Video totally freezes/crashes Raspberry Pi 4 in Chromium

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

Since the Widevine support is available for Raspbian I'm able to watch Netflix and Amazon Prime Video on the Raspberry Pi just using the Chromium Browser.

I have, however, a strange behaviour when trying to browse the Amazon Prime Video Webpage when suddenly the whole system just freezes and only hard reboot (unplugging power) will reset the system. This happens every time. I can open the Page, see the Movies and then the whole system just freezes.

Netflix, youtube is working fine.

Has anyone else ever experienced this behaviour?
Raspbian is updated and upgraded.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I think Raspberry Pi site `https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com` is more suitable for your question

Comment: Oh, wasn't aware that existed, thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue. Opening Prime Video with Chromium causes the page to freeze. I am running Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit with RPi 4 (4 GB RAM). I did install minimal build and then added XFCE desktop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).